# Jason: Mike told me he "was going to" join the football team. - does "was going to" imply Mike later didn't join?

Tags: meaning, backshifting

**Example 1**

> Jason: Mike told me he would join the football team.

**Example 2**

> Jason: Mike told me he was going to join the football team.

"will" and "is going to" in a reported speech often become "would" and "was/were going to."

Are they different?

Does "was/were going to" imply Mike did not actually join later?

Or

None of the usages implies Mike later really joined or will join?

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive conclusion from either statement alone. You'd have to follow up with a statement covering whether or not he did join.

In speech, emphasis on 'would' or 'was' would hint towards him not joining, but you'd still expect a concluding statement to be certain.

> Jason: Mike told me he ***would*** join the football team, if they'll accept him.

> Jason: Mike told me he ***was*** going to join the football team, but later changed his mind.

Each just states intent, not result.